# Chrome Apps have no Icon and are not in Dash available anymore since 16.04

Tags: icons, unity-dash, chromium

There are some applications that are not available for Linux, e.g. Trello or Sunrise Calendar. As long as there is a Chrome App available as an alternative, it doesn't matter much.

However, since I upgraded to 16.04, Chrome Apps do behave differently than with 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, 15.10. They have no unique app icon anymore but show the Chromium standard icon instead. And they are not available via Dash search anymore, which they used to be in the releases mentioned before.

How to make Chrome Apps behave like native apps in Ubuntu 16.04 again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it worked for me when I was on 16.04 (I had to downgrade back to 14.04 due to more serious bugs). Do you create the shortcuts from the Apps tab (chrome://apps) or from the particular page itself? I'm sure I did this from several sites (Google Keep, Facebook Mobile, Messenger) and probably also from Apps (Google Docs) and it worked fine. I had Google Chrome 64bit (not Chromium).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem your referring to is a [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=598160). Until it is fixed you could use Google Chrome which does not have this bug.

**Update**: Now the bug is fixed for me with the latest version of Chromium.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna check this with my system

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded from previous release (it sounds you did) you may try to clear your config files with

`mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome-backup`

and maybe also clear the app shortcuts with

`mkdir ~/.local/share/applications-backup && mv ~/.local/share/applications/chrome* ~/.local/share/applications-backup`

(both commands should create a backup of those config files).

Since the feature in question worked for me after fresh install of 16.04 I suspect some debris from your previous installs may cause your issue.

Comment: Although you're right that my question really sounds like I've updated from previous version to 16.04, matter is, that I refer to installs on different machines. The one in concern running 16.04 has gotten a fresh install of 16.04.